NextAuth with AzureAd
On localhost when I set env variable NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/auth and add redirect url on Azure portal everything works well. I am logged in and have session. But when I deploy app, and set NEXTAUTH_URL=https://my-domain/api/auth and add that to AzureAd. I go to login page on Azure, login and been redirected to https://my-domain/api/auth/callback/azure-ad?code=0.AYIASyr6AMs5qUqN35-Sc7... and get 502 bad gateway (nginx).
This is my AzureAD setup:
AzureAD({
        clientId: process.env.ENTRA_CLIENT_ID,
        tenantId: process.env.ENTRA_TENANT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.ENTRA_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorization: {
          params: {
            scope: "openid profile email api://***************/access_as_user",
            redirect_uri: process.env.ENTRA_REDIRECT_URL
          },
        },
      })

I tried adding multiple types of redirect-url, but id doesnt help. Basically, I just switch from localhost:3000 to my-domain and doesnt work

Add the https://my-domain/api/auth/callback/azure-ad URL to the Azure AD app as Web redirect uri and try again.

You should add the https://my-domain/api/auth/callback/azure-ad in the redirect URI in the code before deploying.

I already did that. It redirects me to that page after I logged in, but it is 502 Bad Gateway. And it just add code as url param.

In local testing
in .env file
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
in Azure ad app registration

In Production
Assume your deployed url is https://my-domain.com
.env
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://my-domain.com
In Azure APP REGISTRATION
https://my-domain.com/api/auth/callback/azure-ad

how should one adapt your answer if the nextJs application is using a basePath in next.config.js ? @dileepa
